# Google Maps v3 PNG Overlay Not Freeing Memory When Released

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a flood inundation website for work (USGS) and am having an issue with freeing the memory of PNG Overlays when a new overlay is selected. Different overlays can be selected by the user which will then display a different inundation map. The problem is after about 4-5 different overlays have been selected, the memory fills up and it stops displaying newly-selected overlays. We are trying to convert our site to Google Maps api v3. We have minimized the PNG file sizes as much as possible (they're an average of 150kb) and I am running out of ideas. I am setting the map to null and also the pngOverlay variable each time a new overlay is selected, yet the memory usage grows about .40 GB with each new selection. I also tried using an .htaccess file to eliminate caching of the PNGs, that didn't work either.

I eliminated all jQuery and working elements from the site to rule everything else out. This version is only the map and the form, with no design elements. Still have the same issue. I have posted a stripped-down version of my code below and also put it on a publicly-accessible server - http://il.water.usgs.gov/ifhp/test/

Any tips/workarounds would be MUCH appreciated! Thanks.

//index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/3col.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/mapv3_3.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
<!--[if lte IE 6]><script src="ie6/warning.js"></script><script>window.onload=function(){e("ie6/")}</script><![endif]-->
    <div>
        <form name="myform">
            <input onclick="loadPNG();" checked="true" type="radio" id="AreaButton" value="Area" name="OverlayType"/>Inundation area<br/>
            <input onclick="loadPNG();" type="radio" id="DepthsButton" value="Depths" name="OverlayType"/>Inundation depth<br/><br/>&nbsp;
            <select onchange="loadPNG();" type="select" id="GageHeightSelect" name="GageHeight" size="9">
                <option selected="true" value="6">&nbsp;&nbsp;570.62 (6.0)</option>
                <option value="7">&nbsp;&nbsp;571.62 (7.0)</option>
                <option value="8">&nbsp;&nbsp;572.62 (8.0)</option>
                <option value="9">&nbsp;&nbsp;573.62 (9.0)</option>
                <option value="10">&nbsp;&nbsp;574.62 (10.0)</option>
                <option value="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;575.62 (11.0)</option>
                <option value="12">&nbsp;&nbsp;576.62 (12.0)</option>
                <option value="13">&nbsp;&nbsp;577.62 (13.0)</option>
                <option value="14">&nbsp;&nbsp;578.62 (14.0)</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
```

//mapv3_3.js

```
var map;
var pngOverlay;
var pngName;
var bounds;
var bounds9;
var bounds10;

var mylatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.62, -88.20);
var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.5222527,-88.1925623); //coordinates for marker 1
var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.69,-88.16638889); //coordinates for marker 2

var curdate= new Date();
var curtime=curdate.getTime();

function initialize() {
//MAP
var mapOptions = {
  center: mylatlng,
  zoom: 11
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

//MARKER IMAGES
var imageRefGage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://il.water.usgs.gov/ifhp/will/images/icon16.png',
    null,
    null,
    new google.maps.Point(16, 16),
    new google.maps.Size(32, 32));
var imageAuxGage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://il.water.usgs.gov/ifhp/will/images/icon16b.png',
    null,
    null,
    new google.maps.Point(16, 16),
    new google.maps.Size(32, 32));
var shad = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
    new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));


//MARKERS
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng1, 
    map: map,
    title:"05540500",
    icon: imageRefGage,
    shadow: null
}); 

var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng2, 
    map: map,
    title:"05540290",
    icon: imageAuxGage,
    shadow: null
});

//SET BOUNDS
// bounds for loading inundation layer png files (default, applies to all but 2 layers)
var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(41.49262999190302, -88.24375135362827);
var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(41.72723485385204, -88.13178850320171);
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);

// bounds for loading inundation layer new_surface9 png file
var swBound9 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.4970009997941, -88.23676753388432);
var neBound9 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.72228131551275, -88.14084620668086);
    bounds9 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound9, neBound9);

// bounds for loading inundation layer new_surface10 png file
var swBound10 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.49696802795427, -88.2368497532207);
var neBound10 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.72231432415114, -88.140818671907);
    bounds10 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound10, neBound10);

loadPNG();
};

function loadPNG() {
if (document.myform.GageHeight.value != "") {
    if (getCheckedValue(document.myform.elements['OverlayType']) == "Depths") {
        pngName = "new_depth" + document.myform.GageHeight.value + "-fs8";
    } else {
        pngName = "new_surface" + document.myform.GageHeight.value + "-fs8";
    }

    pngFile = "http://il.water.usgs.gov/kml_files/png/" + pngName + ".png";

    if (pngOverlay!=null) {
        pngOverlay.setMap(null);
        pngOverlay = null;
    } 

    if (pngName == "new_surface9-fs8") {
        pngOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(pngFile, bounds9); 
    } else if (pngName == "new_surface10-fs8") {
        pngOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(pngFile, bounds10); 
    } else {
        pngOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(pngFile, bounds); 
    }
    pngOverlay.setMap(map);
}
};

function getCheckedValue(radioObj) {
if(!radioObj)
    return "";
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined)
    if(radioObj.checked)
        return radioObj.value;
    else
        return "";
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    if(radioObj[i].checked) {
        return radioObj[i].value;
    }
}
return "";
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't confirm the  leak(tested in FF, chrome crashes immediately when I try to open the page or one of the images).

I guess the issue here is the size of the image(not the filesize, 50kb shouldn't be a problem).

The images used for the Overlay have a size of **6795 x 14239 px**, which must be scaled down to e.g. at the initial zoom 11 to **140x438** , what requires a very high CPU-usage(see [Whats the rationale behind the YSlow rule "Don't Scale Images in HTML"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312584/whats-the-rationale-behind-the-yslow-rule-dont-scale-images-in-html) ).

Try to use images with  appropriate dimensions(depending on the zoom-level)

Comment: You are right. I used [Ground Overlays example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple) and changed it to have the similar behaviour like in this problem and there is no any memory leak. Using `new_surface7-fs8.png` instead of google original image problem appears immediately.

Comment: @Dr.Molle, this appears to have fixed our issue! Thank you so much for taking the time to respond.